# Merge nested dictionaries with common / overlapping keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, I want to merge following two dictionary into one.

How can I merge them efficiently?

**Dict1**

```
{
    UUID('id1'): {
        'due': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'status': 'Done',
    }, UUID('id2'): {
        'due_date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'old_status': 'Done',
    }
}
```

**Dict2**

```
{
    UUID('id1'): {
        'new_val': 'Pass',
        'amount': 123.0,
    }, UUID('id2'): {
        'new_val': 'Fail',
        'amount': 0,
    }
}
```

**Desired Output**

```
{
    UUID('id1'): {
        'due': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'status': 'Done',
        'new_val': 'Pass',
        'amount': 123.0,
    }, UUID('id2'): {
        'due_date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'old_status': 'Done',
        'new_val': 'Fail',
        'amount': 0,
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output? What is UUID() - this is not valid Python.

Comment: @jpp that is by mistake

Comment: OK. In my solution, I've ignored UUID() component and replaced with id. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: yes, That's working perfectly. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `**` unpacking notation together with `dict.get` default parameter of `{}` to combine your dictionaries.

This will handle cases where keys in one dictionary are not in the other, and allow us to iterate the union of all keys.

```
keys = d1.keys() | d2.keys()

res = {k: {**d1.get(k, {}), **d2.get(k, {})} for k in keys}
```

**Result**

```
{'id1': {'amount': 123.0,
  'due': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
  'new_val': 'Pass',
  'status': 'Done'},
 'id2': {'amount': 0,
  'due_date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
  'new_val': 'Fail',
  'old_status': 'Done'}}
```

**Setup**

```
import datetime

d1 = {
    'id1': {
        'due': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'status': 'Done',
    }, 'id2': {
        'due_date': datetime.date(2018, 3, 10),
        'old_status': 'Done',
    }
}

d2 = {
    'id1': {
        'new_val': 'Pass',
        'amount': 123.0,
    }, 'id2': {
        'new_val': 'Fail',
        'amount': 0,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dictionaries `x` and `y`, `z` becomes a merged dictionary with values from y replacing those from x.

In Python 3.5 or greater, :

```
z = {**x, **y}
```

In Python 2, (or 3.4 or lower) write a function:

```
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
     z = x.copy()   # start with x's keys and values
     z.update(y)    # modifies z with y's keys and values & returns None
     return z
```

and

```
z = merge_two_dicts(x, y)
```

Comment: Noted what you found, the issue with syntax of his dict. Once he fixes it he could try this since it should work on an actual dict

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1={
    'UUID(id1)': {
        'due': 'datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)',
        'status': 'Done'
    }, 'UUID(id2)': {
        'due_date': 'datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)',
        'old_status': 'Done'
    }
}
dict2={'UUID(id1)':{
        'new_val': 'Pass',
        'amount': 123.0

}, 
        'UUID(id2)': {
        'new_val': 'Fail',
        'amount': 0
    }
}
finaldict = {key:(dict1[key], dict2[key]) for key in dict1}
print(finaldict)
```

output

```
{
'UUID(id1)': ({'due': 'datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)', 'status': 'Done'}, 
               {'new_val': 'Pass', 'amount': 123.0}), 
'UUID(id2)': ({'due_date': 'datetime.date(2018, 3, 10)', 'old_status': 'Done'}, 
              {'new_val': 'Fail', 'amount': 0})
}
```